# How to get the url of a discarded tab..?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a FF extension, using tabs.discard...
Then, as soon as whichever tab is discarded, its url becomes "about:blank"!
I would like to get the url of such tab...

Say, my extension starts when a tab is discarded, the extension can't access the real url of such a tab...

```
//Extension starts
const tabs = new Map;

async (() => {

  //Here I register some tabs regarding their urls
  //If any tab has already been discarded when this happens, I would miss it 'cause its url would be 'about:blank'
  (await browser.tabs.query({})).filter(tab => matching(tab.url)).forEach(tab => tabs.set(tab.id, tab));

  browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((id, info, tab) => {

    console.log(tab); //discarded: true, url: 'about:blank'
  }, {
    properties: ['discarded']
  });

  //I discard registered tabs to trigger the above listener
  for (let tabId of tabs.keys()) browser.tabs.discard(tabId);
})();
```

I thought about using tabs.reload on tabs that has 'about:blank' as its url and branding tabs with sessions.setTabValue inside webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate before discarding them back!.. But that feels like a hack to me...
Plus, I would miss tabs

Comment: This is a real annoyance and I think FF should implement `tab.pendingUrl` like Chrome does now. Maybe you could open a ticket on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org.

Comment: The ticket already exists: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1620774